# grid-template-column doesn't align items on a row

Tags: html, css

I'm new to HTML and CSS, and I'm trying to create a navigation bar with `grid-template-column`.

The idea that I had is to divide 3 sections of the navigation bar: a section for the logo, a section for the site's main pages, and a section for the socials links.

The problem is that the elements inside the div navBar are not aligned in a row, but the div inside the `menuItems` div and the ones inside the socials div are aligned correctly but with a ridiculous amount of space between them. There is something that I'm missing?

```css
html {
  background: #FFFFFF;
}

body {
  background: #FFFFFF;
  z-index: 0;
}

.navBar {
  z-index: 2;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: [start] 1fr [logo-end] 2fr [item-start] 4fr [item-end] 2fr [social-start] 1fr [social-end];
  grid-template-rows: 70px;
  padding: 1em;
  color: white;
}

.logo {
  z-index: 2;
  grid-column: start/logo-end;
  align-self: center;
  padding-left: 1em;
  padding-top: 1em;
  width: 300px;
}

.menuItems {
  z-index: 2;
  grid-column: item-start/item-end;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  align-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.menuItems>div {
  padding-right: 1em;
  z-index: 2;
  opacity: 0.6;
  justify-self: center;
  align-self: center;
  text-align: center;
  transition: opacity 0.2s;
}

.menuItems>div.active {
  z-index: 2;
  opacity: 1;
}

.socials {
  z-index: 2;
  grid-column: social-start/social-end;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  align-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.socials>div {
  z-index: 2;
  padding-right: 1em;
}


/*TOOL TIPS*/

.tooltip {
  z-index: 2;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext {
  z-index: 2;
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 120px;
  color: #000;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 2px 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 80%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -60px;
  /* Fade in tooltip - takes 1 second to go from 0% to 100% opac: */
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 1s;
}

.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
  z-index: 2;
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

.basicFooter {
  z-index: 2;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  color: white;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 1em;
}

a {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: inherit;
}

a:hover {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: inherit;
}
```

```html
<!-- Head -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.5.0/p5.js"></script>
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/053ac89fca.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<!-- Body -->
<!--script src="scripts/mainSketch.js"></script-->
<div class="navbar">
  <div class="logo">
    <a href>
      <img src="logo.png" alt="SDiCesare.it" width="180" height="60">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="menuItems">
    <div class="active">
      <a href> Home </a>
    </div>
    <div class="active">
      <a href> Shop </a>
    </div>
    <div class="active">
      <a href> Projects </a>
    </div>
    <div class="active">
      <a href> Github </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="socials">
    <div>
      <a href="https://github.com/SDiCesare">
        <div class="tooltip">
          <i class="fa-brands fa-github" style="font-size:24px;color:black" /></i>
          <span class="tooltiptext">GitHub</span>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div>
      <a href="https://www.instagram.com/simone.greil/">
        <div class="tooltip">
          <i class="fa-brands fa-square-instagram" style="font-size:24px;color:black"></i>
          <span class="tooltiptext">Instagram</span>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Note that you have a typo error in line 32 of your HTML with `<i />...</i>`. The first slash in the opening tag does not belong there! Then your approach for a navbar is unlucky. This is not a good task for CSS-Grid but Flexbox. Then you should follow some semantics such as using the correct tags. A navbar has a semantic tag `<nav>` which behaves the same as a div. Last but n to least you should use a list for the links by using the `menu` tag and the `<li>` as list items for the links themselves. There is also no need to wrap those into divs.

Comment: Change the .navBar selector to .navbar to match the class you set in the HTML

Answer (score -2):

You have an inconsistency between the naming of the class in the HTML and the CSS. In the HTML it's named `navbar` and in the CSS it's named `navBar`

Comment: typos should be pointed out in comments and not as answers. If that would be solely caused by typos then the question should be flagged and closed as `Not reproducible or caused by typos`. I'm aware that you unlock comments at 50 reputations. However, it is not allowed to use an answer option as a workaround to account limitations.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).